# How to change the font in the terminal of server?

Tags: server, fonts

I'm running a 10.04 server at home. Is it possible to install the new Ubuntu font used in the 10.10 Desktop versions on my server and configure it so the console uses it when I hook up a monitor to it while I'm working on it (for when SSH isn't working)?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: No idea really but you can probably figure it out with `man setfont` and `/etc/default/console-setup`. See this thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=329369. If you find out make sure to post the answer here!

Comment: Cool, I'm going to mess around with the font settings and as soon as a the monospaced Ubuntu font is ready I'll post the answer (unless it's going to be the default font when that happens)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ubuntu font has no monospaced version, so it's not suited for use in a terminal or console that has fixed width character cells.

In addition, console fonts are special bitmap fonts, not TrueType/OpenType fonts (but OTOH it shouldn't be too difficult to create a console font from a monospaced TrueType font).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know the difference between monospaced and non monospaced fonts. Good to know :).

Comment: Actually, there now is the Ubuntu Mono variant of the font.

Answer (score 7):

Try the following command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

Answer (score 0):

I like [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63824/can-i-change-the-linux-console-ctrlaltf1-font-to-ubuntu-mono):

```
setfont /usr/share/consolefonts/UbuntuMono-R-8x16.psf
```

this is an example; you can see a list of available fonts like this:

```
ls /usr/share/consolefonts
```

and should you for some reason not have them, you can install them like this:

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-ubuntu-font-family-console
```

note that you may need to put the setfont command in your .profile or .bashrc as it may need to be run upon every login