# Can I change the Linux console (Ctrl+Alt+F1) font to Ubuntu Mono?

Tags: fonts, console, ubuntu-font-family, virtual-console

Is there a way to set a specific TTF font to be used on the console? (I believe you might have to convert it to a bitmap font?)

If it needs to be converted, what tools can I use to do the conversion? Otherwise, how do I pick Ubuntu Monospace for my console font?

(I already have the Ubuntu Monospace font installed from the beta PPA for it.)

*Edit:* I already set `gnome-terminal` to use **Ubuntu Mono**. Now I'm wanting to set the all-text screens I get when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to use the same font.

Comment: On 11.04 Appearence>Fonts>Last option, it has to be a Monospace font. Or using gconf-editor: desktop/interface/monospace_font_name.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

By [joining the font beta testing team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-typeface-interest/+join), the PPA details given in the sign-up email let you enable a Personal Package Archive that contains:

- `fonts-ubuntu-font-family-console` *("Ubuntu Font Family Linux console fonts, sans-serif monospace")*

after enabling the PPA you can do:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
2. `sudo apt-get install fonts-ubuntu-font-family-console`
3. `setfont /usr/share/consolefonts/UbuntuMono-R-8x16.psf`

*Note that the [font hinting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_hinting) that enables the bitmap generation is still a work-in-progress by [Vincent Connare](http://connare.com/) at [Dalton Maag](http://www.daltonmaag.com/).  Please give feedback about the look of the 8×16 rendering to bitmaps and how they could be improved at:*

- [launchpad.net/ubuntu-font-family/+filebug?field.title=Mono: 16ppem Hinting: ...](http://launchpad.net/ubuntu-font-family/+filebug?field.title=Mono:+16ppem+Hinting:+...)

PPEM means "pixel per em" and is the number of pixels allocated to the design square when rendering at any size.  For the Linux/VGA console this is 16 pixels high.  For your question about the *tools involved* (after the instructing/hinting has been done), the tools are:

1. `otf2bdf`
2. `bdf2psf`

If you `apt-get source ttf-ubuntu-font-family` in Ubuntu 11.10 beta, then the code already exists in the `debian/console/*` source directory (just type `make`). >This was disabled for the moment because the two small utilities listed above are in *Universe*, rather than Ubuntu's *main* component and will need Main Inclusion Reports first.

The bug to follow and add your comments to is:

- [Bug #861334](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-font-family-sources/+bug/861334) *("Ship Ubuntu Mono .psf as default console font in Ubuntu 11.10")*

Because of the extreme deadlines involved, it is *not likely* to happen by default until the next release cycle of Ubuntu (after which Vincent will have had a chance to incrementally tweak the hinting work too!).

Comment: Is the PPA still needed? I can install `sudo apt-get install fonts-ubuntu-font-family-console` without adding a PPA in Ubuntu 15.04. and it successfully changes on my console, when I type `sudo setfont /usr/share/consolefonts/UbuntuMono-R-8x16.psf`

Comment: But on my 3200x1800px console the font is really tiny, so as a **larger font**, I would choose `setfont /usr/share/consolefonts/Uni3-TerminusBold32x16.psf.gz` see my answer on [resize-font-on-boot-message-screen-and-console](http://askubuntu.com/questions/548522/resize-font-on-boot-message-screen-and-console)

Comment: @rubo77: `setfont` doesn’t require privileges higher that the user currently logged on a tty (virtual console).

Answer (score 0):

As converting seems to produce "irregular" fonts, I propose to use this ready font as a workaround:

```
git clone https://github.com/powerline/fonts.git powerlinefonts
cd powerlinefonts

# only this .psf are available
find -name "*psf*"
cd Terminus/PSF

# renaming
sudo apt install rename
rename -v 's/ter/Uni2/' *.gz
rename -v 's/powerline-v/Tarminus/' *.gz

# copy fonts to relevant folder
sudo cp *.gz /usr/share/consolefonts

# set font for tty
sudo nano /etc/default/console-setup
# paste this:
CODESET="Uni2"
FONTFACE="Tarminus"
FONTSIZE="18b"

# Go to tty: Ctrl + Alt + F3
sudo setupcon -f
```

This is roughly equivalent to selecting a Terminus font with:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow console-setup 
# then in tty:
sudo setupcon -f
```

Comment: fonts-ubuntu-font-family-console is unavailable now