# How can I set and get the tty console font?

Tags: console, tty, fonts

1.How can I set the font and size of the TTYs?

The command:

```
dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

allows me to choose certain fonts/sizes that cannot be installed (an error message appears after the reconfig. process). Moreover, the values set in `/etc/default/grub` alter everything. Sometimes you are using a font, but after rebooting it is changed.

2.How can I know what font/size is the console using in a certain moment.

There is a how to in the community pages to set the TTY resolution but it has no description of its interaction with the font/size of the console during boot and after.

Comment: Yes, you follow a how-to but it does not work because what is determining the console-font and size is another set of things like the resolution of the screen at boot time, which you set according to a different thing, like the splash screen blur, and which doesn't allow you to set the font-family, it changes it according to something else
So how do you effectively set the font-family and size of the console font? That is the question. In the settings panel there are only very few things you can configure.

Comment: To answer your question #2 refer to my answer http://askubuntu.com/a/529552/295286

Comment: You should do this:  **cd /usr/share/consolefonts/; setfont fontname.psf.gz**

Answer (score 0):

I asked the exact same query @ ubuntu forum in 2006.

- console resolution depends on vga parameter. You can get from 640x480 upto 1920x1080 resolution, last checked on ubuntu. (don't know the vga parameter for 1080p but I have seen it after default ubuntu install on my machine.)
- to change linux console font try searching for "consolechars" program, its in console-tools package I think.
- also see -> [Can I change the Linux console (Ctrl+Alt+F1) font to Ubuntu Mono?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63824/can-i-change-the-linux-console-ctrlaltf1-font-to-ubuntu-mono)
- psf font editor -> NAFE -- not another font editor @ http://nafe.sf.net/