# Is there a way to check which font your shell/terminal emulator is using from the commandline?

Tags: command-line, fonts

Is there a way to check which font your shell/terminal emulator is using from the commandline?

I am willing to settle reading part of a config file, if a direct command is not readily available.

Comment: May contents of `cat ~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/%gconf.xml` help?

Answer (score 11):

The option **Use the system fixed width font** is usually equal and set by  `org.gnome.desktop.interface`.

[image: screen0]

- **To get current font setting run following command:**

  ```
  gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface monospace-font-name
  ```
- **To set/change setting run following command** (here example of increase size) :

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface monospace-font-name 'Ubuntu Mono 14'
  ```

As I run above command, I found font of your terminal changed (increased size)! So, `gnome-terminal` using that font setting.

Comment: Thanks! I was desperately trying to find out the "system fixed width font" Ubuntu uses to also use it in urxvt.

Comment: But what if they do not use GNOME, but something else, like me?

Answer (score 8):

DE-independent way of getting system's preferred monospace font:

```
$ fc-match Monospace
DejaVuSansMono.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Book"
```

Ref: ArchWiki [Font configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Font_Configuration#Query_the_current_settings)

Comment: Doesn't work when in Ubuntu using Cinnamon. I have a custom mono font and still get the same output as you.

Answer (score 3):

Check terminal font:

```bash
grep -i "fontface" /etc/default/console-setup
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many answers on console emulators here already, so I'll focus on tty virtual console only.  You can do cat `/etc/default/console-setup` and find the line saying FONTFACE. Alternatively you could `grep -n FONTFACE /etc/default/console-setup`

For instance, here's my console-setup file

[image]

To change it, you can execute  `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` in tty. This will update the kernel settings, by the way.

Comment: I tried your method and it mentioned `fontface="fixed"`, while @Pandya's answer gave me `'Ubuntu Mono 13'`.. Wonder why there is a difference?

Comment: @alpha_989 Because Pandya's answer relates to GUI terminal emulators, while mine - to the TTY virtual consoles. Both are valid for their respective purpose.

Comment: My `/etc/default/console-setup` has `CODESET="guess"`, `FONTFACE="Fixed"`, and `FONTSIZE="8x16"`. Is there any way to use this information to figure out which glyps can actually be shown? I don't seem to havy any font file in `/usr/share/consolefonts` that obviously matches these specs.

Answer (score 1):

You can check your gnome terminal font using following command

```
gconftool-2 --get /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/font
```

For example it am using this command for gnome-terminal

```
 [guru@guru-pc:~]$gconftool-2 --get /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/font
  Monospace 12
```

If you want to change the font using command line you can use following command

```
  gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/font --type string "courier new 12"
```

Where 12 is the size of font.

Comment: In my env (16.04.3, plasma, KDE) this suggestion errors with `No value set for '/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/font'`.  Nevertheless, following Pandya's answer (using the `gsettings` command instead) actually works and returns the Gnome terminal font.

Comment: Same here.. using `ubuntu 16.04` Gnome.. not sure why this didn't work.. but `Pandya'a` answer worked..

Answer (score 0):

For XFCE terminal You can grep the configuration file:

```
$ grep 'FontName=' ~/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc 
FontName=Victor Mono Bold 13
```