How can I tell which font xterm is using?
I'm on ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. Most everything is out-of-the-box, no customization.
When I press ctrl+alt+t, a terminal emulator appears (xterm-256color), and that emulator uses a custom font, "monospace". That seems to be a style of font, not a specific font. How do I search online for this font, then? my environment
(I'm hoping the answer to this allows me to search for which UTF-8 characters can be displayed with this font.)

QTerminal is xterm-256color too, and its font Ubuntu Mono seems the same as Monospace of gnome-terminal. And Ubuntu Mono is the real font.

@StasSimonov "Ubuntu Mono" is not the font in my terminal.
[differences] 1
[google's "Ubuntu Mono"] 2

@StasSimonov I think you're right that Ubuntu Mono is the font. When I run gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface monospace-font-name (from https://askubuntu.com/questions/527412/is-there-a-way-to-check-which-font-your-shell-terminal-emulator-is-using-from-th), it returns Ubuntu Mono 13. However, I don't yet know what explains the visual differences.

Your "terminal font" seems to be "DejaVu Sans Mono": https://i.sstatic.net/UrOhKKED.png

@FedKad I think you're right. "Monospace" and "DejaVu Sans Mono" seem to be the exact same font, by visual inspection. Why these two font options point to the same font is another question. Can you post your comment as an answer so I may reward it?

Visually inspecting, I see that the your
"terminal font" seems to be "DejaVu Sans Mono".

Your system (probably) does not have a font called "Monospace". You can search for it with something like:
$ find /usr/share/fonts -iname '*monospace*'

which will probably return nothing.
The closest thing you can do is:
$ fc-match monospace

which returns
DejaVuSansMono.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Book"

on my system.
See also this answer.
