# How to set the console font size?

Tags: command-line, configuration, console

If I enter the command

> ctrl-alt-f1

The first console is displayed. The default font of this is way to small and I want to reset it. On other Linux and Unix like systems I can easily do this with the command

> dpkg-reconfigure console-setup

If I enter this command on Ubuntu, the font size will reset. However, once I reboot, it will go back to the default small font. Why is this? How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try http://askubuntu.com/a/553721/248158 ?

Comment: Yes, I did try it and it doesn't work. When the system is rebooted the console font goes back to its default.