# Change Font color and size when booting into CLI ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: boot, command-line, fonts

I was wondering if there was a way to increase font size and change font color when booting into CLI in ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
The font is small and white on black, I want it to change the font colour.
If anyone can help, that would be great. 
I am ready to provide any system details if needed.

Thanks

Comment: With `gnome-terminal` you can do that from the Preferences for your profile.

Comment: Check this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/548522/resize-font-on-boot-message-screen-and-console