# ubuntu-server installation: is there a way to change the font size in BusyBox?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, server, busybox

when installing ubuntu-server on a new laptop the default font of the installer and the BusyBox console is extremely small. is there a way to make it bigger while the system is running from a boot `.iso`?

there is a `setfont` command but i have not found out how to use it (yet?).

---

update: i got a little further but the font remains unchanged. what i did:

```
# udpkg -i /cdrom/pool/main/c/console-setup/console-setup-linux-fonts-udeb_*_all.deb
# # maybe 'udpkg -c ...'?
# cd /usr/share/consolefonts
# gunzip Lat38-VGA16.psf.gz  # or some other font
# setfont Lat38-VGA16.psf
```

Comment: Busybox doesn't handle fonts. Do you mean https://askubuntu.com/questions/173220/how-do-i-change-the-font-or-the-font-size-in-the-tty-console?

Comment: @muru as my question is about the BusyBox i get while installing. i have no `dpkg` yet...

Comment: This will set you on the correct path: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=146038

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/63867/158442 for an example of `setfont`. No idea if there are any alternate fonts available by default, or how you'd install one if there aren't any.

Answer (score 0):

*busybox loadfont* worked in desktop Xubuntu and to my understanding should do in Ubuntu servers too. I tested with another font but the result should be the same with Lat38-VGA16.

```
gunzip /usr/share/consolefonts/Lat15-TerminusBold14.psf.gz -c >/tmp/t
busybox loadfont </tmp/t
```

Answer (score 0):

When booting, you are presented with the grub menu. Here you can press esc,and 'e' to edit.
Find the line beginning with linux and add vga=784
press F10 to boot.
This dos not EXACTLY what you asked for, but I believe the effect is?

For more info on VGA=..., take a look at: http://pierre.baudu.in/other/grub.vga.modes.html.

Comment: Please expand your answer further, rather than just giving a link.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, provide a more concise answer, being  a total newbie on ask-ubuntu :)

Comment: The answer is much better now after the edit :)