# How can I make my terminal display non-standard characters?

Tags: gnome-terminal, fonts, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I am working on some UTF-8 text files whose content is in another language. Most of the text displays correctly, but some characters show up like this:

```
<U+200C>
```

How can I make my terminal display such foreign language characters correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can set your local settings to utf-8, but it is not possible to set it only for terminal. [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8859/can-a-gnome-terminal-profile-use-utf-8-by-default)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `consolefont` that holds these characters. lat9w-16 or Lat2-Terminus16 seem fairly populair.

Old, but this should still work:

[Can I change the Linux console (Ctrl+Alt+F1) font to Ubuntu Mono?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63824/can-i-change-the-linux-console-ctrlaltf1-font-to-ubuntu-mono)